# I have an array with multi-dimension, I want to get the name of the array and the value of array

Tags: php, arrays

Problem in splitting array in PHP.

I need `pradm_policy_risk_attr_details_motor_id => 20170825113749907`.

but in array only. Below is my example how to I needed in array

```
$array = [pradm_policy_risk_attr_details_motor_id => 20170825113749907,
column_11 => BP-2-B1534,
column_14 => Mahindra];
```

How can get this?

This is my array

```
array:19 [
  "pradm_policy_risk_attr_details_motor_id" => array:1 [
    0 => "20170825113749907"
  ]
  "column_11" => array:1 [
    0 => "BP-2-B1534"
  ]
  "column_14" => array:1 [
    0 => "Mahindra"
  ]
  "column_15" => array:1 [
    0 => "Bolero-Camper 2WD (2523 cc)"
  ]
  "column_61" => array:1 [
    0 => ""
  ]
  "column_92" => array:1 [
    0 => "0.000000"
  ]
  "column_28" => array:1 [
    0 => "[SELECT]"
  ]
  "column_29" => array:1 [
    0 => "Closed"
  ]
  "column_30" => array:1 [
    0 => "0"
  ]
  "column_32" => array:1 [
    0 => "Owner Driver"
  ]
  "column_33" => array:1 [
    0 => ""
  ]
  "column_35" => array:1 [
    0 => "Excavator"
  ]
  "column_36" => array:1 [
    0 => ""
  ]
  "column_69" => array:1 [
    0 => ""
  ]
  "column_70" => array:1 [
    0 => ""
  ]
  "column_24" => array:1 [
    0 => ""
  ]
  "column_16" => array:1 [
    0 => "Select"
  ]
  "column_121" => array:1 [
    0 => ""
  ]
  "column_122" => array:1 [
    0 => ""
  ]
]
```

Comment: `$new_arr['pradm_policy_risk_attr_details_motor_id']=$result['pradm_policy_risk_attr_details_motor_id'][0];`

Comment: Are you using Laravel

Comment: Yes i am using laravel

Answer (score 0):

If you need to 'flatten' the whole array, try [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). The way it works is you define a function, that receives a single array item, transforms it and returns transformed value, then you pass that function to array_map in order to perform said transformation on all elements of the array:

```
function flatten($item){
    return $item[0];
}

$original_array = Array(...); // assign your original array here
$flattened_array = array_map('flatten', $original_array);
```

Or using anonymous function syntax:

```
$flattened_array = array_map(function($item){return $item[0]}, $original_array);
```